# Type error when trying to modify values using .loc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Trying to modify all values in the column of a dataframe where values in another column is equal to something specific.

I'm using a dataframe `df`, with columns a,b,c,d. I first duplicated column d using

df["e"] = df["d"]

Then, using `.loc`, I went for:

```
df.loc[df["d"] == "Unknown", "e"] = "Not Unknown!"
```

And I'm getting a:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I'm terribly confused since this has worked in the past, in other cases, and I can't seem to figure out what might be happening. For info, dtype of "d" is a string. If I straight up `.loc` it it returns the expected result.

Since I'm changing all values of column d, I also thought that my copying the column might be the problem, so I tried copying it over using a different method with:

```
df = df.assign(e=pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(df))).values)
```

But got the same result.

Thanks for any help catching my (what I'm sure will be) obvious mistake!

**EDIT**: sample from df,

      `a           b          c     d       e
0  21838344    00001       50  Unknown  Unknown
1  35652924    00001       80  Unknown  Unknown
2  35652925    00001       80  Unknown  Unknown
3  31206900    00001       80  Unknown  Unknown
4  37544700    00001       80  Unknown  Unknown`

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Your solution works fine. Check for whitespace so you don't have `'Uknown '` or similar anywhere.

Comment: samething here. although even the whitespace shouldn't matter. It just wouldn't replace the value. So bizarre

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd


data = [['2334','00001','50','Unknown'],['6754','00001','80','Unknown']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['a','b','c','d'])

df['e'] = df['d']

df.loc[df['d'] == 'Unknown', 'e'] = 'Not Unknown!'
```

Completely works for me.

Comment: Really sorry, it is indeed there, when changing column names I deleted too much.